# How do you set attributes in Boo Lang

Tags: boo

How would you write the following code in Boo?

```
// Armor.cs
using Parse;

[ParseClassName("Armor")]
public class Armor : ParseObject
{
}
```

Comment: IIRC same as in C#. Example: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Useful+things+about+Boo#UsefulthingsaboutBoo-Example.

Comment: i dont understand your answer.. i mean, i dont see any example of this in the link you supplied. thanx anyway

Comment: it's right there, `[Singleton]`

Comment: but that is said to make the class act as singleton... it is not what is want to achieve

Comment: What's important is that it's an **attribute**, which is what your question is about, right?